# Free scripting in Construct 2?

Tags: scripting, construct-2

In [Construct 2 example about creating an animated player](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/413/direction-based-sprite-animation), they used more than 8 events:

4 events to store movement direction into `Direction` variable from `Player.8Direction.MovingAngle`

4 events to select animation based on `Direction` value

1 event to stop animation

Apparently if would be much easier to do the same with simple if-else code with 4 or 5 cases. Is it possible in `Construct 2`?

**UPDATE**

I didn't find scripting, but was able to express the same example in more condensed way:

[image]

All names are from example.

Answer (score 1):

Construct 2 has no direct support for scripting, although it's possible to create modules with JavaScript. There's documentation on how to do this on Scirra's website. A link to the documentation can be found here: [Official C2 SDK documentation](https://www.scirra.com/manual/15/sdk)

As for if-else statements, C2 *does* have them.